# Unit test directory exception in Azure Pipeline which passed on local PC

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-devops

Basically, I want to use a C# test file which under the subdirectory of solution folder.
Here is the test data directory on local PC.

"C:\code\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security\CommonLibraryTests\ConditionInfoData\TestData"
By implementing the
"TestDataFolder = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName, "CommonLibraryTests\ProductCollector\TestData");"

I can get the testdata, so the test code passes. But when I check this solution in Auzre Pipeline, the test results shows me, "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\a\2_work\29\s\CommonLibraryTests\ProductCollector\TestData'."
The correct path on Azure Pipeline should be
"'D:\a\2_work\29\s\SECURITY\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security\CommonLibraryTests\ProductCollector\TestData'."

I am thinking that is there any way to get at least this part "D:\a\2_work\29\s\SECURITY\SECURITY\R11.06.00\common\src\Platform.Security\CommonLibraryTests"?

Pic below is my testAssemblies and Excute build agent detail.
[image]
[image]

Get the reliable path

Comment: runing  `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();`
I got  `D:\a\2\_work\29\s\TestResults\Deploy_tfsservice 2022-04-05 09_49_12\Out `
This reason I dont use `Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName, "SECURITY\\R11.06.00\\common\\src\\Platform.Security\\CommonLibraryTests\\ProductCollector\\TestData");` is the rev number could be different in future which is R11.06.00 right now.

Comment: I tested many path methods, please check for reference.
` Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;Environment.CurrentDirectory;``D:\a\2\_work\29\s\TestResults\Deploy_tfsservice 2022-04-05 09_49_12\Out  `
` this.GetType().Assembly.Location;`:`D:\a\2\_work\29\s\TestResults\Deploy_tfsservice 2022-04-05 09_49_12\Out\CommonLibraryTests.dll`
`string stupPath = Application.StartupPath;`:`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow`